# Div should be come in center onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not perfect in jquery, there is a problem in my code. In this code i have 4 div fix height and width. problem is that when i click on any div, clicked div should come in center (horizontal and vertically).

Here is the my code> http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/02asmj4w/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.col').click(function(){
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var divWidth = $(".col").width();
        var divHeight = $(".col").width();
        var test=(windowWidth-divWidth)/2;
        var marginLeft = $(this).css({"margin-left":(windowWidth-divWidth)/2});
        var margintop = $(this).css({"margin-top":(windowHeight-divHeight)/2});

        $(this).animate({ 
            width : '250px', 
            height:'250px', 
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
var divWidth = $(".col").width();
var divHeight = $(".col").width();
```

You got element's default value `100` (and, by the way, you use `.width()` for getting height) instead of `250`, which element has after animation.

You can simply set both these variables to `250`:

```
var divWidth = 250;
var divHeight = 250;
```

**Update**. Also for correct centring you can either hide all other `div`s:

```
$('.col').not(this).hide();
```

or set `position` of element to `absolute`.

```
$(this).css("position", "absolute");
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02asmj4w/3/).

It will be, of course, much better to use constant (variable) for `250`, not just having multiple magic `250` values in code.

Comment: But still that are not coming in center,and not in your Updated fiddle.

Comment: @Maddy first `div` only works, yes. To avoid all this mess with jumping `div`s you can hide all other `div`s. Is it acceptable for you?

Comment: @Maddy otherwise, `$(this).css("position", "absolute");` can be used to position element.

Answer (score 0):

completely reworked the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/02asmj4w/15/
why? because i had the urgent need for some fiddling early in the morning...

what does my solution do:
- it centers the clicked box horizontally and vertically inside the viewport

- if another box gets clicked, the current centered box goes back to its initial position
- if the centered box gets clicked, it goes back to its initial position
- the four initial boxes stay on top of the page
- there is no more jumpy animation due to your initial used float...

what have i done:
- every div now has an id in addition to the class.

- the class css looks as follows

  .col {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       float: left;
       margin-left: 10px;
       margin-top: 5px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
   }
- the id css just sets the left position of every div, and set some different background colors to better distinguish the boxes

  ## div3 {

  ```
  left: 220px;
  background: #cde;
  ```

  }

ok ... that was only the styling thingies, nothing special here...
now for the js:

```
var leftOffset; //declare a global variable leftOffset for later usage

$('.col').click(function () {              // on click
    if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {    // if clicked div is not the centered one
        // get viewport dimensions and set needed margins
        var currentViewPortWidth = $(window).width();
        var currentViewPortHeight = $(window).height();
        var marginLR = (currentViewPortWidth - 250) / 2;
        var marginTB = (currentViewPortHeight - 250) / 2;
        leftOffset = $(this).css("left");  // store clicked div left offset in global var 

        $(".clicked").animate({            // define the 'go back to initial pos' animation
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px',
            left: leftOffset,
            marginLeft: '10px',
            marginTop: '5px'
        }).removeClass("clicked");         // remove 'clicked' class handler

        $(this).animate({                  // define 'clicked div go to center' animation
            width: '250px',
            height: '250px',
            left: '0px',
            marginLeft: marginLR,
            marginTop: marginTB
        }).addClass("clicked");            // set clicked class handler


    } else {                               // else means: clicked div is the centered one
        $(this).animate({                  // define the 'go back to initial pos' animation
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px',            
            left: leftOffset,
            marginLeft: '10px',
            marginTop: '5px'
        }).removeClass("clicked");
    }
});

// ensure, that the div stays centered on window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    var currentViewPortWidth = $(window).width();
    var currentViewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    var marginLR = (currentViewPortWidth - 250) / 2;
    var marginTB = (currentViewPortHeight - 250) / 2;
    $('.clicked').css({"margin-left": marginLR, "margin-top": marginTB});
});
```